# Get value from specific attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, prtg

I'm using PRTG and I want to monitor my parking system. The system generates a XML file and I would like to know what xPath expression I need to use, when to extract only the MODE value of the Alarmtype, for example Door

```
<ResponseParameters>
<Alarms>
<Alarmtype Id="Door">
<Mode>Ok</Mode>
</Alarmtype>
<Alarmtype Id="Printer">
<Mode>Failure</Mode>
</Alarmtype>
<Alarmtype Id="Barrierstate">
<Mode>Failure</Mode>
</Alarmtype>
</Alarms>
</ResponseParameters>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: The question lacks clarity

Comment: So is `ok` your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression and see if it works:

```
//ResponseParameters/Alarms/Alarmtype[@Id="Door"]/Mode/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, but no luck

```
//ResponseParameters/Alarms[Mode/@Alarmtype = 'Door']
```

I am not familiar with xPath, so I try to read many posts and websites. 
But hopefully someone can point me to the right direction.